# ZeroDivisionError while trying to plot corelation matrix

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the corelation matrix from pandas dataframe

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data_for_corelation.csv', delimiter=';')
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B'])
plt.matshow(df.corr())
plt.show()
```

But I am getting an error at this line:

```
plt.matshow(df.corr())
```

And error is:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in figaspect(arg)
   2759     if isarray:
   2760         nr, nc = arg.shape[:2]
-> 2761         arr_ratio = nr / nc
   2762     else:
   2763         arr_ratio = arg

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Sample data:

```
print(df.head(10))

       A           B
0  249,640704  1,019356
1  242,324502  0,647166
2  243,495232  0,644257
3  243,310156   0,81684
4  243,511297  1,050207
5  239,435233  1,340164
6  240,091439  1,836193
7   241,08975  1,540461
8  237,017175  1,244953
9  236,141326  1,210147
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: Did you try `pd.read_csv(..., decimal=",")` to take into account that your data is using a decimal comma (instead of the default dot)? Did you check the types of the dataframe columns? Did you try `print(df.corr())` to check whether it made sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I run this line of check-code on your sample data:

```
df.describe()
```

I get this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   A       10 non-null     object
 1   B       10 non-null     object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 144.0+ bytes
```

This tell me that pandas is reading your two columns as `str`, not as "numbers". This is due the use of the character `','` as decimal separator, instead of `'.'`, as already suggested by [JohanC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374439/zerodivisionerror-while-trying-to-plot-corelation-matrix#comment110314764_62374439).
You can solve this problem by fixing the data-read operation:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=';', decimal=',')
```

If I check again the dataframe, after this fix, I get:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   A       10 non-null     float64
 1   B       10 non-null     float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 224.0 bytes
```

As you can see, this time your columns are interpreted as "numbers" (`float`). Then you can perform the correlation matrix:

[image]